# Angular 7 activated routes all active after refresh

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7, angular-routerlink, routerlinkactive

When I reload/refresh my app the routes in the menubar are displayed and all of the items are set to `active`. I have configured for the Routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home',
    data: { title: undefined }
  },
  {
    path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,
    data: { title: 'Login' }
  },
  {
    path: 'home', component: MainComponent,
    data: { title: 'Home' }
  },
  {
    path: 'search',  component: SearchListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Search'}
  },
];
```

In my menu-bar I have reduced the code to the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <a routerLinkActive="is-active" 
       routerLink="/login">Login</a> |
    <a routerLinkActive="is-active" 
       routerLink="/search">MySearch</a> |
    <a routerLinkActive="is-active" 
       routerLink="/home">MyHome</a> |
</div>

<div >
  <div *ngFor="let route of router.config">
    <a routerLinkActive="is-active" 
        [routerLink]="userName? ('/'+route.path ): '/' ">{{route.data.title}}... {{userName? ('/'+route.path ): '/' }} </a> |
  </div>
</div>
```

which includes my routes twice - nearly identical - except that the second code generates the items dynamically. The first one selects the items properly  after a refresh while the second one fails.

According to the [docu](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) `routerLink` can be used as string

Anybody could explain me why the second one fails?

**EDIT:**
As requested a picuture

[image]

but the content remains the same after I have chosen another link! Than all links are rendered properly!

**EDIT2**

I was able to [reproduce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ha2rnk) the error. Main issue is that the evaluation of the `routerlink` was done too late and I run into the same issue like on the already [reported bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18469).

My current workaround solution: initially set the `userName` :-/

Comment: Can you attach rendered HTML from *ngFor ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` to your generated links. By default Angular router will match any part.

Comment: Tried, but the effect remains the same :-/ I guess it has to do with the rendering which isn't called again....